# "Workspace.Plane.Propeller.Script:37: attempt to index number with 'Transparency'" error in Roblox studio, how do I fix it?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a propeller spin using transparency. I have duplicated models (including 4 unions in them) and changing the rotation of them. But it gives me the error in the title.
Please help me I've tried so many resources but none of them work. I would really appreciate it. Thank you all in advance.

```lua
local plane = script.Parent.Parent

local p = script.Parent

local p0 = p.Propeller0:GetChildren()
local p1 = p.Propeller1:GetChildren()
local p2 = p.Propeller2:GetChildren()
local p3 = p.Propeller3:GetChildren()
local p4 = p.Propeller4:GetChildren()
local p5 = p.Propeller5:GetChildren()
local p6 = p.Propeller6:GetChildren()
local p7 = p.Propeller7:GetChildren()
local p8 = p.Propeller8:GetChildren()
local p9 = p.Propeller9:GetChildren()
local p10 = p.Propeller10:GetChildren()
local p11 = p.Propeller11:GetChildren()
local p12 = p.Propeller12:GetChildren()
local p13= p.Propeller13:GetChildren()
local p14= p.Propeller14:GetChildren()
local p15 = p.Propeller15:GetChildren()
local p16 = p.Propeller16:GetChildren()
local p17 = p.Propeller17:GetChildren()
local p18 = p.Propeller18:GetChildren()
local p19 = p.Propeller19:GetChildren()
local p20 = p.Propeller20:GetChildren()
local p21 = p.Propeller21:GetChildren()
local p22 = p.Propeller22:GetChildren()
local p23 = p.Propeller23:GetChildren()
local p24 = p.Propeller24:GetChildren()
local p25 = p.Propeller25:GetChildren()
local p26 = p.Propeller26:GetChildren()
local p27 = p.Propeller27:GetChildren()
local p28 = p.Propeller28:GetChildren()
local p29 = p.Propeller29:GetChildren()


while true do

    for c in p0 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p1 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p29 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p1 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p2 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p0 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p2 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p3 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p1 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p3 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p4 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p2 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p4 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p5 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p3 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p5 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p6 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p4 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p6 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p7 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p5 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p7 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p8 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p6 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p8 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p9 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p7 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p9 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p10 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p8 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p10 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p11 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p9 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p11 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p12 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p10 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p12 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p13 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p11 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p13 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p14 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p12 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p14 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p15 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p13 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p15 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p16 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p14 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p16 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p17 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p15 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p17 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p18 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p16 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p18 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p19 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p17 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p19 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p20 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p18 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p20 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p21 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p19 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p21 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p22 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p20 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p22 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p23 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p21 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p23 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p24 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p22 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p24 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p25 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p23 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p25 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p26 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p24 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p26 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p27 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p25 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p27 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p28 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p26 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p28 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p29 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end
    for c in p27 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
    wait(.1)
    for c in p29 do
        c.Transparency = .5
    end
    for c in p0 do
        c.Transparency = 0
    end

    for c in p28 do
        c.Transparency = 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetChildren()` returns an array.](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Instance)

You then use that array as an [iterator](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html).

```lua
for c in array do
    c.Transparency = .5
end
```

I do not know how the iterator is implemented under the hood but I assume it's a wrapper for [`ipairs`](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html), and ipairs returns two values; the index and the value. Since you try to index the index, it will throw this error. In any case, you would need to write:

```lua
for _, c in ipairs(array) do
    c.Transparency = .5
end
```

Where you ignore the index (denoted as `_`).

Unrelated, but please do not use this excessive amount of copy pasta. Use loops and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on Luke100000's answer, here's how you could use arrays and loops to clean up your answer.

Notice how your propeller animation follows a pattern :

- a becomes visible
- b becomes half transparent
- c becomes transparent

So we're going use an array to simplify this pattern down so you only have to write your code once.

```lua
local parent = script.Parent
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local ANIMATION_INTERVAL = 0.1 -- seconds 

-- hold onto all of the propellers in an array
local propellers = {}
for _, child in ipairs(parent:GetChildren()) do
    -- capture the number from the name
    local _, _, index = string.find(child. Name, "Propeller(%d)")

    if index then
        -- use the number as the index in the array, but offset it by 1
        propellers[index + 1] = child:GetChildren()
    end
end

-- create a helper function for setting transparencies
local function setGroupTransparency(parts, t)
    for _, p in ipairs(parts) do
        p.Transparency = t
    end
end

-- use the RunService Heartbeat to loop without using a while-true loop
local lastUpdate = 0.0 --seconds
local propellerIndex = 1
RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function(deltaTime)
    lastUpdate += deltaTime

    -- escape if it's not time to animate
    if lastUpdate <= ANIMATION_INTERVAL then
        return
    end

    -- reset the counter
    lastUpdate = 0.0

    -- figure out which propellers we're animating
    local i = propellerIndex
    local iLessOne = if i == 1 then #propellers else (i - 1)
    local iPlusOne = if i == #propellers then 1 else (i + 1)
    
    -- update the animation step
    setGroupTransparency(propellers[iLessOne], 1)
    setGroupTransparency(propellers[i], 0.5)
    setGroupTransparency(propellers[iPlusOne], 0)

    -- update the counter so the animation continues
    propellerIndex += 1
    if propellerIndex >= #propellers then
        propellerIndex = 1
    end
end)
```